# Attacking moves

Tags: analysis, learning, beginner, attack

While playing chess against a computer I am able to analyse what the computer is going to move even at the highest difficulty level but I am not able to place good moves against the computer. Can anyone tell me how can I improve?

Comment: As it is written, this question seems a bit vague to me. For instance, how have you determined that you are unable to find good moves to play? Have you analyzed your games afterwards and found this out, or do you get stuck without seeing how to proceed during the games? Also good would be to post a game of yours so that the community could get a feel for your general level of play.

Comment: Actually yes I analysed some of my games but how can I post a a game means a normal game is very long how can I post it

Comment: @Bitthal Maheshwari  Copy and paste the PGN here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't give exact tips specifically catered to your gameplay as you have not provided information on how you generally open your games, but here are a few general tips.

1) Develop Bishops and Knights (get them out into a more accesable spot)

2) Control the center 4 squares of the board so that the opponent can't move their peices through the center (use the 2 center pawns and knights)

3) "Connect" pieces so that if one is taken, the square can be retaken. The centeral pieces should be protected by multiple pieces.

4) Castle your king (This is often somewhat overrated, this shouldn't be your immediate priority but should be done soon after controlling the center if possible) A king behind 3 pawns that are max 2 rows ahead is generally a strong defense, I find putting the king and 3 pawns in a diamond formation to be the best  defense.

5) Avoid moving out your queen to early, keep it protected so you can use it more in the end game.

6) Don't create extensive pawn chains, generally try to just use 2 central pawns and then the one diagonal from the queen then use knights and bishops.

Here's a decent trap for beginner players: Move your bishop infront of your knight, wait for an opening and then take out the rook in the opposing corner.

I hope this helps.

Comment: @AntonMenshov it doesn't improve much. That's one of the items for not accepting an edit.